# Send SMS through php, AT commands

Tags: php, sms, at-command

I'd like to send SMS through a GSM gateway using php. I want to send AT commands directly to the modem. Should I try and interface with minicom or something similar? Should I just use sms server tools? Is there an easier way to do this?

Using Debian btw.

Also, as a follow-up, what is a decent GSM modem that I can use with a standard SIM card, and that would work with the aforementioned programs.

Comment: are you sure there is no answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sending+sms+modem

Comment: Are you not able to use a third-party SMS gateway? They often have easy to use API's and allow you to send SMS's in bulk. Might be easier and quicker than interfacing with a modem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy to make an SMS manager in php - actually it's not that easy to make a reliable SMS manager at all, modems are a peculiar breed.  SMS server tools is easy to set up, reliable and feature rich so I wouldn't bother and just setup sms tools.

Wrt modems, I think most should work.  We are using Cinterion TC65's and they work well, but I am sure many others will work equally well.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm looking for something under 100 USD, are the cinterion terminals fairly expensive?

Comment: A better comment I guess is, I'm not sure where to find a decent low to mid priced gsm modem. I don't really need a terminal for bulk distribution

Comment: No it's quite expensive due to its feature set, and apparently production has ended in the mean time.  Can't recommend other units though, might be best to have a look at some support forums, like the one on the sms server tools site.